What is the name of this permutation?
Let $m, n$ be positive integers.
Does the permutation $\sigma_{m, n}$ of degree $(m + n)$ defined by
$$\sigma_{m, n} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \cdots & n & n + 1 & \cdots & m + n \\ 
m + 1 & \cdots & m + n & 1 & \cdots & m \end{pmatrix}$$
have a specific name or notation?
The action by $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\sigma_{m, n}}$ can be described informally as swapping the subset $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\{1, \dots, m\}}$ with its complement $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\{m + 1, \cdots, 
m + n\}}$ with respect to the standard linear ordering on $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\{1, \dots, m + n\}}$.
It appears for example in the proof of Theorem III.2.4 in the book Quantum Groups by C. Kassel. In our notation, the permutation $\sigma_{p, n - p}$ is used to switch $(p, n - p)$-shuffles with $(n - p, p)$-shuffles in the proof.

You described it as swapping two subsets, but it's only such  a swap if $m=n$. Also, its order is only $m+n$ if $m$ and $n$ are coprime. I don't know if this permutation has a name, but it is simply the $n$-th power of an $(m+n)$-cycle.

@JaapScherphuis I appreciate your comment. Regarding the first question, I misunderstood 'order' with 'degree', so I will edit the question. Also, the word swapping should be confusing as you mentioned, so I will rewrite that part as well.

One expression I have heard is "Caesar shift", owing to this type of permutation being the basis for the Caesar cipher.

Your permutation can be given the form of a permutation matrix which has the peculiar block form :
$$\Pi = \begin{pmatrix}0&I_m\\I_n&0\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$
Remark, $\Pi$ being a permutation matrix : $\Pi^{-1}=\Pi^\top \tag{2}$
In this way, the properties of the permutation are better understood ; in particular, we have the following theorem :
Let $M =\left(\begin{array}{c|c}A & B \\ \hline C& D \end{array} \right)\in\mathbf{R}^{(n+m)\times (n+m)}$ be a block partitioned matrix with, in particular $A\in\mathbf{R}^{m\times m}$ and $D\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$, then $\Pi^{-1} M\Pi=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}D & C \\ \hline B& A \end{array} \right)$ using $\Pi$ defined in (1).
(Theorem for example mentionned here)..
This theorem explains the importance of the "Caesar permutation" (terminology recalled by Especially Lime)

Any comment ?...
